# Nesting IF and AND statements

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, formula

I'm trying to nest IF statements together, so that when it reads through the data, it will be able to categorize it into 3 separate types. [The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVEuw.png) shows my formula thus far, but its returning VALUE! after I enter it.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't include your formula this should be helpful:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C6,{"A","B","C"},0)),"Slip...",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C6,{"D","E","F"},0)),"Personal...","Not"))
```

Per your comment your formula should be:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C6,{"Slip Trip Fall","Fall down Stairs","Knock, Trip or Fall within bus"},0)),"Slip Trip Fall", IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C6,{"Alighting incident","Boarding incident","Struck by object","Personal Injury Event","Wheelchair / Buggy incident"},0)),"Personal Injury Event",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C6,{"Collision","Collision incident"},0)),"Personal Injury Event",FALSE)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, and yes, you are exactly right, my apologies. I see entirely what you have done there! I have now amended it to this. `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C6,{"Slip Trip Fall","Fall down Stairs","Knock, Trip or Fall within bus"},0)),"Slip Trip Fall", IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C6,{"Alighting incident","Boarding incident","Struck by object","Personal Injury Event","Wheelchair / Buggy incident"},0)),"Personal Injury Event","IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C6,{"Collision","Collision incident"},0)),"Personal Injury Event"") `. This is throwing the error message "there is a problem with this formula".

Comment: @ThomasMckillen Please see the edit. You can change `FALSE` into something that suits your needs.